# Reputation display

Tags: bug, status-bydesign

I just got an announcement that by getting 2000 rep, I can edit questions and answers without review.  The title bar shows my rep as 1990.  I clicked on my icon in the title bar to see if that would cause an update, but it didn't.  It is probably a difference in update times for the different pieces of the site, but it has persisted for a while.  More amusement than a real problem.

Comment: Presumably someone voted for you, triggering the announcement, then retracted the vote.

Comment: @Emilio explained it well

Comment: @m0sa quick note - that didn't ping me.

Comment: @Emilio it only pings you once you've participated in that particular post's comment thread (like now)

Comment: @m0sa I know. I was just wondering why you used it.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to force a recalculation of your reputation, the reputation page at

https://physics.stackexchange.com/reputation

will give you an exhaustive breakdown and force a recalc. I currently see your reputation  at 2,010, so you're above that threshold, but as dmckee notes it is perfectly plausible for someone to have upvoted one of your answers, triggering the announcement, and then retracted the vote.

Votes can be retracted [within the first five minutes after they're cast](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/34323/im-getting-your-vote-is-too-old-to-be-changed-for-a-vote-i-made-less-than), in which case they do not show up in your reputation history. They can also [be retracted if the post is edited](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19235/is-this-a-bug-in-voting-or-is-it-supposed-to-work-like-this), in which case you will get a corresponding `-10` on your reputation history, with the explanation `unupvote`.

[image]

For more information, see [What are the limits on how I can cast, change, and retract votes?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5212/what-are-the-limits-on-how-i-can-cast-change-and-retract-votes) at the mother meta.